# Pausing current thread via user input, in console window application

Tags: c#, multithreading, input, console

This is the solution I came up with to pause/resume an active thread inside a console...

It requires a second thread for input, which the main loop reacts too. But my ignorance of C# makes me wonder if there is a simpler solution? Perhaps one that can be done with the main thread alone?

Essentially, I am testing several things that will iterate at the defined FPS, and I want to be able to pause and resume the iteration via keyboard input. Any feedback is appreciated.

```
class TestLoops
{
    int targetMainFPS = 5;
    int targetInputFPS = 3;
    bool CONTINUE = true;

    Thread testLoop, testLoop2;
    ConsoleKeyInfo cki;

    ManualResetEvent resetThread = new ManualResetEvent(true); //How to correctly pause threads in C#.
        public void Resume() { resetThread.Set(); }
        public void Pause() { resetThread.Reset(); }

    public TestLoops()
    {
        //_start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        Console.Write("CreatingLoop...");

        this.testLoop = new Thread(MainLoop);
        this.testLoop.Start();

        this.testLoop2 = new Thread(InputLoop);
        this.testLoop2.Start();
    }

    void MainLoop()
    {
        long _current = 0;
        long _last = 0;

        Console.Write("MainLoopStarted ");
        while(CONTINUE)
        {
            resetThread.WaitOne();

            _current = DateTime.Now.Ticks / 1000;
            if(_current > _last + (1000 / targetMainFPS) )
            {
                _last = _current;

                //Do something...
                Console.Write(".");

            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
    }

    void InputLoop()
    {
        long _current = 0;
        long _last = 0;

        Console.Write("InputLoopStarted ");
        while(CONTINUE)
        {
            _current = DateTime.Now.Ticks / 1000;
            if(_current > _last + (1000 / targetInputFPS))
            {
                _last = _current;

                //Manage keyboard Input
                this.cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
                //Console.Write(":");
                if(this.cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Q)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("'Q' was pressed.");
                    CONTINUE = false;
                }

                if(this.cki.Key == ConsoleKey.P)
                {
                    this.Pause();
                }
                if(this.cki.Key == ConsoleKey.R)
                {
                    this.Resume();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestLoops test = new TestLoops();
    }

}
```

Comment: Frame rate is usually not maintained by pausing for arbitrary values (like 10ms that you chose). What are you actually trying to accomplish, regardless of the pause/resume functionality?

Comment: Nothing more then repeating something till I am satisfied with what I see (in this case repeated dice mechanic results). It is mostly just for testing. However, I am trying to learn as I go and if there is a more appropriate way of doing this I would like to learn.

Comment: Curious... Why remove the C# from my title? :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify it drastically by using the non-blocking [`Console.KeyAvailable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.keyavailable.aspx) check. That way, you can execute all your code from the main thread:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class TestLoops
{
    const int targetFPS = 5;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool _continue = true;
        DateTime _last = DateTime.MinValue;

        while (_continue)
        {
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey(true);

                if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Q)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n'Q' was pressed.");
                    _continue = false;
                }

                if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.P)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n'P' was pressed; press 'R' to resume.");

                    // Block until 'R' is pressed.
                    while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.R)
                        ; // Do nothing.

                    Console.WriteLine("'R' was pressed.");
                }
            }

            DateTime _current = DateTime.Now;
            if (_current - _last > TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000F / targetFPS))
            {
                _last = _current;

                // Do something...
                Console.Write(".");
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Replying to comment.

Be careful. The code below blocks due to the `Console.ReadKey` call, not due to the `while` loop. The `while` loop is there only so that, if the user enters a character other than `R`, the program would discard it and wait for another character to be entered.

```
// Block until 'R' is pressed.
while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.R)
    ; // Do nothing.
```

If you wanted to block until *any* character is pressed, you would simply use:

```
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Comment: That second line should probably say: `'R' was pressed; press 'P' to pause again`?

Comment: Thanks, that would do it. I am curious though. While blocked, is the thread essentially paused waiting for another ConsoleKey input? 

Which means that the ManualResetEvent is nothing more then a wrapped version of that type of block?

Comment: Just noticed the simplification of the DateTime... Thanks! That also helps a lot.

Comment: In a way, yes. There are several blocking mechanisms: `Thread.Sleep` waits for a time to elapse, `Console.ReadKey` waits for keyboard input, and `ManualResetEvent.WaitOne` waits for a signal (typically issued from the user code itself). 

Blocking on a `Console.ReadKey` call is functionally equivalent to waiting on a `ManualResetEvent` which will be signalled (by another thread) when keyboard input is available.

Comment: I have learned several things from your example. Namely, simplifying the DateTime, blocking the thread via an internal do nothing loop, and the Main() is already a thread (thus not requiring an explicit Thread creation)... Very helpful.

Comment: Note comment above. And yes, any code in your application _must_ be executed by a thread. When .NET launches your application, it creates what one may call the “main thread”, and executes your static `Main` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, yes. The only thing that you could consider is making sure that the worker thread stops even if it was previously suspended, when you press the `Q` key:

```
if(this.cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Q)
{
     CONTINUE = false;
     this.Resume(); // <-- make sure that the worker thread resumes
}
```

As a side note, constant FPS is usually maintained by **skipping frames** as appropriate, rather than pausing a thread. Pausing a thread is imprecise, and doesn't allow fine tuning animation speeds. `Thread.Sleep` can also behave differently on different hardware, and can have rather poor resolutions (a minimum OS timeslice is around ~16ms IIRC).

Comment: I am not familiar with skipping frames. :/ Something new for me to learn if I ever get to putting something on the screen. As for now I am using Unity to render, and I am using the console to test math and object ideas absent an actual game space.